# PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS does not use environment block of the new parent

Tags: c++, windows

I'm reading [this article](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2009/11/22/quickpost-selectmyparent-or-playing-with-the-windows-process-tree/), the code works but process does not use the environment variable of the selected parent process.

e.g As SYSTEM I created a process, and selected `explorer.exe (running as Administrator)` as the parent, the new process inherit environment variable from the SYSTEM process, instead of the Administrator one.

I know this is by design, so I tried to read the environment block from the `explorer.exe` then use it as a parameter to CreateProcessA. But windows did not provide a API to read the Environment Block of another process.

Any ideas? I just need to set the correct environment blocks.

Comment: CreateProcess() has the option to specify the environment instead of inheriting it.  The trouble is knowing the environment of another process.  Very ugly.  This kind of hackorama is [written in C#](https://github.com/gapotchenko/Gapotchenko.FX/tree/master/Source/Gapotchenko.FX.Diagnostics.Process#readenvironmentvariables) these days.

Comment: You can get the token of the session user via [`WTSQueryUserToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsqueryusertoken) and create a fresh environment block for the user via [`CreateEnvironmentBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-createenvironmentblock) with `bInherit` as false. Do not try to implement what `CreateEnvironmentBlock` does on your own. It touches many registry keys and API functions that vary depending on the OS version.

Comment: I don't recommend trying to read the environment block in production code because Microsoft refuses to document the offset in [`_RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-rtl_user_process_parameters). (The large number of system details that Microsoft refuses to publicly document with an API contract is deeply frustrating.)